# Trying to display thumbnail img's side-by-side with css display: inline-block

Tags: javascript, css, image

I am fairly new to development and stumped on this after spending several hours trying to fix. Below is part of the JS that will display the thumbnail img's in html based on search results. Once a thumbnail is clicked it will open a related youtube video but my question is how to line these img's side by side?[Current results I get from my CSS below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qexao.jpg)

```
function renderResult(meal) {
  return `
    <div class="meal-wrapper">
      <p class="meal-name">${meal.strMeal}</p>
      <a href="#ingredients-modal" rel="modal:open">
        <p class="meal-video">Click to see ingredients & instructions!</p>
      </a> 
      <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="${meal.strYoutube}">
        <img src="${meal.strMealThumb}" class="meal-thumbnail-image">
      </a> 
    </div>`
}
```

I have set CSS to align the images side-by-side. This is the closest I have came to getting them to align next to each other. If I use only inline-block they still stack vertically.

```
.meal-thumbnail-image, .drink-thumbnail-image 
{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 12%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Below is a portion of the html where the JS search results/html posts to, fyi.

```
<main class="main" role="main" aria-live="assertive" hidden>
    <h2>Find your dinner video below!</h2>
    <div class="js-meal-search-results"></div>
</main>
```

I am still pretty new so I appreciate any advice. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: can you please add a codepen for the above scenario?

Comment: Just added the link, thanks Ramesh https://codepen.io/Jonheye1/pen/QJxejv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below css to the wrapper like below:

```
.meal-wrapper{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rameshvr/pen/yQQxWM

PS: I would recommend using css flexbox/grid approach for this kind of layout. Please refer here:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Hi Ramesh, one question, seems to solve the problem but the last img ends up showing slightly below the img to it's left. I tried adding a vertical-align:top to the div but didn't seem to help?

Comment: oh yea, you mean the one on the 4th column, right? with title "French Onion Soup"? this is because of the length of titles are different. you can try setting a 3 column layout if it works.

Comment: Yeah, I searched a few different options but looks like it's always the end one that dips...trying to see what causes this. I'll look into that with grid perhaps.

Comment: Looks much better. Did you just change the width to 33.3 to accomplish that? Looks like the font size of the titles are better proportionally as well.